Definition of Random Set
I'm studying the definition of "random closed sets", but I came across two definitions, the first is from Crauel's book and the second I found in Molchanov's book.
$X$ is a Polish space and $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mathbb{P})$ a complete probability space.
Definition 1: A set-valued map $C: \Omega \to 2^X$  is called a random set in $X$ if the mapping $\omega \mapsto d(x,C(\omega))=\inf\{d(x,a): a \in C(\omega)\}$ is $(\mathcal{F},\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$ measurable for all $x\in X$. A random set $C: \Omega \to 2^X$ is called a random closed set if $C(\omega)$ is nonempty and closed for each $\omega\in\Omega$.
Definition 2: A map $B:\Omega \to \mathbb{E}$ from a probability space to the
family of closed sets in a Polish space $X$ is called a random closed set if, for every
open set $G$ in $X$ $\{\omega: B(\omega)\cap G \neq \emptyset\}\in\mathcal{F}$.
I would like to understand if these two definitions are equivalent. However, I also question myself, in the motivation of these definitions, why I could not think of a definition as
$F\subset \Omega\times X$ is a closed randon set if $F_{\omega}=\{x: (\omega,x)\in F\}$ is closed.

What is $dist$ there?

@ThomasAndrews I clarified in the post. Is the distance function between any point and any non-empty set.

So, when you say $2^X,$ you mean $2^\Omega?$

@ThomasAndrews No, in definition 1, $C$ maps from a probability space to the set of subsets of X.

The two definitions are equivalent (proposition 2.4 in Crauel's book).
For your second question, I think that the problem is that if only the fibers are closed the set may not even be measurable. Take $F=[0,1]\times V\subset[0,1]^2$, where $V$ is the Vitali set. $F_\omega = [0,1]$ or $F_\omega=\emptyset$ for every $\omega\in[0,1]$.
